# How to sum up Total Income and Total Indirect Income Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to sum up total income and total indirect income. This total values in html table comes using jQuery by providing a class. But now I want to sum up two table total values in a single variable and put in a new html table.

The new html table looks like we have a column total (income+indirect income) = variable. [Click to see the HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw3Qd.png)

How can I do that using jQuery. [Click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REWce.png) and see that the values of total amount column are sum up and lies in the footer on every table. But now I want to sum up two table values in a single variable and that new variable I want to put in a new html table on a same page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var total_1 = 0;
    $('.income-amount').each(function(i, obj) {
        total_1 += parseInt($(obj).text());
    });
    $('#income-total').text(total_1.toFixed(1));
});
```

I use this jQuery in the Html table for total amount column sum up.

Below is the html table.

```html
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive-xl">
        <caption style="caption-side:top; text-align: center;"><h3>Income</h3></caption>
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
         {#  <th>S No.</th>#}
         <th>Particulars</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Total Amount</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in all_profit %}
    {% if item.category.under == "Income" %}
        <tr>
            {#  <td>{{  }}&nbsp;</td>#}
                <td>{{item.category}}</td>
                <td>{{item.category.desc}}</td>
                <td class='income-amount'>{{ item.balance }}&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td style="visibility:hidden;"></td>
            <td style="visibility:hidden;"></td>
            <td id='income-total'>Total:</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry but what is the actual issue you are having when trying to do this? What is it doing wrong and what error are you getting?

Comment: I dont know how can i do that? I want to calculate total income + total indirect income

Comment: When i try to catch the total value using jquery it provides nan.

Comment: Well I think this might be off-topic but before we get to that could you please [edit] the question and put the table in using the table markdown? Please see: [Should we disapprove of uploading images of tables when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403699/12672179) for more information

Comment: Sorry I'll explain a bit better. Implementation questions are off-topic normally while debugging questions are not. Yours seems like implementation but i'm not certain if you are debugging